# Undersired echo truncate in sh Linux

Tags: linux, shell, echo, sh

I want to send two variables as input to another command in shell script. I have tried many methods to send the two variables but I am getting unexpected problems with echo command.

```
        #!/bin/sh
        echo $DATE_NOW1
        Feb 17 2016
        echo $HOURS1
        13:06:47
        echo "$DATE_NOW1 $HOURS1"

        output : 13:06:4716
```

the above string gives unexpected truncated output.i am getting the Variables after reading from a file.(ex : HOURS1=`cat time_now |cut -d '.' -f 1` )

I have tried other methods like foo="$date_now $hours" and foo "${date_now}${hours}" but still no use.

Can anyone point me where am I getting it wrong ?

Comment: First, bash is case sensitive. Second, where do the uppercase variables come from?

Comment: @Shitsu: I have edited the question

Comment: The apparent problem here is a file with DOS line endings.  This is an extremely common FAQ and is covered extensively in the [`bash` tag wiki](//stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). I am voting to close this as "trivial typo".

Comment: @tripleee: I think that's not the case as the file with the variables was also generated in linux. So I would rule out DOS line endings.PS: I tried to check for DOS line endings in Vim and now  rule out DOS endings

Comment: The file you are reading the value from, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable DATE_NOW1 is terminated by a \r character. As `echo` always finishes the display by a \n, `echo $DATE_NOW1` works well (actually displays `Feb 17 2016\r\n`). But when you concatenate, `echo` displays this string :
`Feb 17 2016\r13:06:47\r\n`

Try to remove the tailing \r, or add a \n at the end of `DATE_NOW1`

Comment: This answer was for the first un-edited question. Seeing the new question, the answer is now different. Your DATE_NOW1 variable ends with a \r caracter. When using echo alone on this variable, echo adds a tailing \n. But when you concatenate the variables, echo adds only a tailing \n, meaning your un-converted string is "Feb 17 2016\r13:06:47\r\n"

Comment: yup removing \r did the thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE_NOW1="Feb 17 2016"
HOURS1=13:06:47
echo "$DATE_NOW1 $HOURS1"
```

You must use quotation marks because spaces.